# How to set a alphanumeric sender id for sending messages to Indian recipient using Twilio?

Tags: twilio

We are using twilio for SMS service, and using JAVA as a backend service for twilio integration. When user receives a message, 5xxxx number appears on screen as a sender's number. But we want to predefine sender's name as short name of our organization, but couldn't seek any help from the provided documentation. Our organization is based in India, please guide to resolve the same.

Expecting to predefine SMS sender's name as a short name of organization, but couldn't find appropriate help using Twilio's documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here,

I believe what you are looking for is an [Alphanumeric Sender ID](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181348-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-for-Twilio-Programmable-SMS), which will allow you to have a personalized sender ID (like a short name of your organization) instead of your Twilio number.

You mentioned that your organization is based in India. Are you using numbers from India? Because unfortunately, Alphanumeric Sender ID is [not supported in India](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID).

Comment: Yes, you got my point correctly.
We want to display our organization's nick name instead of numbers in the recipient's inbox. The numbers are random such as 5757****, etc. 
Is there any other way to get this replace a number by text.

Comment: I believe the only way to do this is via Alphanumeric Sender ID, so there aren't any other options.